# How to delete a "space" in IBM Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have created an extra "space" on my Bluemix account.
I double checked my Bluemix dashboard, but I am not able to delete that space. Now, how I can delete it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the cloud foundry CLI (`cf`) to delete a space. Please note that you need to have the 'Organization Manager' role in order to be able to delete a space.

Use the following command:

```
# cf delete-space <space-name>
```

If you don't have `cf` command line installed in your environment, you can install it from here:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases

Alternatively via Bluemix dashboard:

1. Select the "Account and Settings" button (top right button, looks like an empty face)
2. Click on "Manage Organizations". The UI changes to Manage Organization
3. Select the space you want to delete on the left panel
4. You will see the space name on the middle panel and a delete button

**When you delete a space all applications and services on that space will also be deleted, so use this command with caution.**

Comment: Thank you @Alex da Silva. I just deleted the wrong space by using the `cf` command line interface.

Comment: I used the cf command line interface because the Bluemix web site displayed an error while deleting it.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no command to `undo` it. If you have your apps locally you can push them to another space.